# Single word describing a person who has an obligation

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word (noun) describing a person or a legal party that has an obligation to do something. A nicer way of saying "obligated party".

A made up example:

> The court obliged Jim to pay 1000$ of satisfaction. Jim is obliged. In this context Jim is a ... ?

Comment: Can you give us a sentence in context please?

Comment: Just added one. It's not very nice but maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat technical/legal term, but **[obligor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obligor)** is the word.

> *noun*
>   *Law*
>   a person who owes or undertakes an obligation to another by contract or other legal procedure.

Comment: Beware the spelling & pronunciation, though: /ˈɒblɪgɔː, ˌɒblɪˈgɔː/ as different from that of *obliger*, /əˈblʌɪdʒə/.